# Hive Binary and String Datatype

Tags: oracle11g, hive, bigdata

Is there any max limit for the binary and String data type on Hive. The idea is to able to store data larger than 4 GB. Oracle supports till 8 TB of data in a CLOB data type column. DO we have a similar storage capacity through Hive.

The format I'm using to store the data on hdfs is parquet and to store the string/binary data I it uses bytearray datatype along with annotations. How do I know the max limit for the bytearray datatype of parquet format.

In the doc it state that the byte array can be of arbitrary length. So does it mean I can store data up to 8 TB or more than that.

Answer (score 2):

No, Hive does not support BLOB/CLOB datatypes.  A `STRING` datatype supports data up to 2GB, but that's not sufficient for your requirement.

However, Hive is mainly a query tool to use SQL to retrieve data stored in the underlying HDFS file system, and HDFS most definitely can handle files of arbitrarily large size.  (More here: [Hadoop HDFS maximum file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493873/hadoop-hdfs-maximum-file-size))

I am guessing your goal is to get the values stored in Oracle over to Hadoop.  I would be surprised if your goal was to actually *return* the value in a subsequent Hive query -- in that case, you're out of luck.

If you are using Sqoop to import data from Oracle, it will be fine, but there are some special considerations.  See [documentation on Large Objects in section 7.2.9](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects).

Alternatively you can move the large objects to Hadoop using Hadoop filesystem commands (e.g. `get` or `put`) as long as the source system has the Hadoop command line tools installed.

In any case, any logic that may need to access the contents of the large object (perhaps it's an image, for example) would need to use a different strategy than SQL/CLOB as with Oracle.  Perhaps reference the HDFS filename in the content and `get` it when needed for display?

Hope this is helpful and that I have answered the right question.